# Replacing a part of a string in multiple columns

Tags: sqlite

In a SQLite database with multiple tables that can contain multiple columns of type `text` with content that looks like:

```
C:\path\to\file1\[rest of path and file name]
```

Is it possible to run one command that would replace all of those values with something like:

`D:\path_to\file2\` (without changing the rest of path and file name)?

Answer (score 0):

No. A single [UPDATE statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) works on a single table.

You have to execute one statement for each table, and you have to know (or explicitly [read](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info)) the column names.

Comment: Ok, and is there a one statement that would do the change in one table with multiple columns of unknown name (like in the question)?